# Webalizer causing high CPU load

Tags: apache-2.2, performance-tuning, cpu-usage, webalizer, nice

We use [webalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webalizer) to generate reports on our Apache access logs - it is useful in conjunction with Google Analytics.

The problem is that webalizer uses ALOT of CPU when running. If I run `top` I can see two perl processes with 90% CPU - this slows down the machine and therefore the website for our users.

Webalizer is run via a daily cron job (`/etc/cron.daily/00webalizer`):

```
#! /bin/bash
# update access statistics for the web site
if [ -s /var/log/httpd/access_log ]; then
   exec /usr/bin/webalizer -Q
fi
```

Does anyone know how to limit how much CPU webalizer can use? For example, would `nice` help and how would I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having monitored the situation for a while I have an embarrassing confession - **Webalizer** was not causing the load spike on our server. It was actually caused by **logwatch**, *a different log file analyser*. Both scripts were running at the same time (via `cron.daily`) and I only figured out which one was causing the issue by disabling one, then the other and comparing the CPU usage.

We don't need logwatch because I have never even seen the emails it produces. So, I disabled it by deleting the symbolic link in `/etc/cron.daily/`:

```
> ls -l /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 17 03:46 /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch -> /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/logwatch.pl
```

Problem solved. Sorry [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) - didn't mean to falsely accuse you of being a CPU hog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes nice would help, it lower the process priority so your webserver and thus users get priority.

```
exec nice /usr/bin/webalizer -Q
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try. Will it lessen the CPU load at all?

Comment: No, but webalizer will only get scheduled when nothing else wants the CPU time

Comment: After using `nice` for a few days I can report that unfortunately it isn't the silver bullet I was hoping for - webalizer is still overloading the server when it runs.